# How to create a simple calculation in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery, this will become very apparent.

I'm trying to basically learn jquery by applying it to small ideas.

In this case it's the Z-score formula in statistics.

z = x-mu/sigma

Here is how i'm approaching it in my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var x = $('input[name="xValue"]').val();
    var mu = $('input[name="muValue"]').val();
    var sig = $('input[name="sigmaValue"]').val();
    var total = x - mu / sig;

    function calculate() {
        $('.result').html(total);
    }
});
```

One concept that i have captured is to store your values in variables and then manipulate them that way.

What i'm struggling with is what to do with it next. In this case i want to output the result when an event is fired (onclick).

Here is my markup:

```
<section class="formula">
    <div class="z"></div>
    <div class="x">
    <input id="xValue" type="text" name="x" autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="mu">
        <input id="muValue" type="text" name="mu">
    </div>
    <div class="sigma">
        <input id="sigmaValue" type="text" name="sigma">
    </div>
    <div class="result"></div>
    <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Don't nest calculate() function inside document ready handler, you are facing a scoping issue here. Of course, your calculated variables should be inside calculate() function too

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k6X5C/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny great fiddle, thank you this is also a solid approach, would this just be an anonymous function and I see how this could just a function that could be run by all objects with a .calculate class, do you think this is good practice or it is always better to name your functions? Not sure how to define both bases in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do like:
change your html as:

```
...
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
...
```

to

```
..
<button type="button" class="calculate">Calculate</button>
....
```

and in js, a click handler for button with class `calculate`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".calculate").click(function() {
        var x = $('input[name="x"]').val();
        var mu = $('input[name="mu"]').val();
        var sig = $('input[name="sigma"]').val();
        var total = x - mu / sig;
        $('.result').html(total);    
    });
});
```

Demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rzUj/)

Comment: That's usually better (advised) than inline script +1

Comment: @Sudhir your fiddle shows perfectly what i did wrong, thank you for explaining the proper way to do that. Thanks A. Wolff for the follow up commment

Comment: @Sudhir in your opinion assuming this code only needs to be used in one instance would it be necessary to give this function a name, make it an anonymous function, or just keep it wrapped in the doc.ready function which it doesn't need to be I mean it could just be without the doc ready in a script.js file as well. Thanks.

Comment: @MARS it doesnot need a function... wrapping in doc ready would suffice.. as long as you can confirm jquery is available om page you can add the code to some js file

Comment: If using only + and - with VAR you will end up adding letters to the string. See @Richa Jain answear to be sure you are doing math.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $("#btncalc").on('click', function() {
   event.preventDefault();
   var x = parseInt($("#xValue").val());        
    var mu = parseInt($("#muValue").val());
    var sig =parseInt($("#sigmaValue").val());
    var total1 = x - (mu / sig);
    alert(total1);           
    $('div.result').html(total1);

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AxcKY/)

Comment: + for parseInt()

Answer (score 0):

Well, i would like to point couple of mistakes here.

First, wrap your calculation logic inside the `calculate` function like this.

```
    function calculate() {
     var x = $('input[name="xValue"]').val();
     var mu = $('input[name="muValue"]').val();
     var sig = $('input[name="sigmaValue"]').val();
     var total = x - mu / sig;
     $('.result').html(total);

}
```

Next, you are selecting your `input` with name `xValue` but in your html its name is only `x`. Either change its name or use the selector `input[id="xValue"` or `$("#xValue").val()"`

And finally, when you're using jQuery its better to avoid inline script.
Use

```
$("#calculateButtonID").click(function(){
    //calculate logic here...
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVNky/)

Comment: thank you for pointing out the error and giving those 2 very good tips on wrapping calculate function and not using inline script.