# jQuery calculate multiple text fields using a selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here a situation, I would like to calculate different text fields using a selector.

Here is an example of the form that I have...

```
    <input type="text" name="qtr1-revenue-month-1" id="qtr1-revenue-month-1" class="qtr-revenue editable" value="<?php echo $teamLeadMainForecast['qrt1Month1Revenue']; ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="qtr1-revenue-month-2" id="qtr1-revenue-month-2" class="qtr-revenue editable" value="<?php echo $teamLeadMainForecast['qrt1Month2Revenue']; ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="qtr1-revenue-month-3" id="qtr1-revenue-month-3" class="qtr-revenue editable" value="<?php echo $teamLeadMainForecast['qrt1Month3Revenue']; ?>" />

    <input type="text" name="qtr1-margin-month-1" id="qtr1-margin-month-1"  class="qtr editable margin" onblur="calculateQtrMonth.call(this,event)" value="<?php echo $teamLeadMainForecast['qrt1Month1Margin']; ?>" />
   <input type="text" name="qtr1-margin-month-2" id="qtr1-margin-month-2"  class="qtr editable margin" onblur="calculateQtrMonth.call(this,event)" value="<?php echo $teamLeadMainForecast['qrt1Month2Margin']; ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="qtr1-margin-month-3" id="qtr1-margin-month-3"  class="qtr editable margin" onblur="calculateQtrMonth.call(this,event)" value="<?php echo $teamLeadMainForecast['qrt1Month3Margin']; ?>" />
```

Here is what I'm looking to do.

When I make a change to the text field with id qtr1-margin-month-1 I want to have it multiply qtr1-margin-month-1 and qtr1-revenue-month-1.

How would I go about making the calculations using the jquery selector?

Thank you,
Kevin

Comment: What did you tried ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242051/how-to-create-a-simple-calculation-in-jquery

Comment: You need a selector for each element in order to get that specific element's value. There are no shortcuts

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any example Code or Values? Where should the output go? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: PHP echo is not useful for a question where PHP is irrelevant. Rather copy the outerHTML from dev tools, include what you have tried as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[id^='qtr1-margin-month']").change(function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    var idNum = $self.attr("id").substr(-1);
    var product = parseInt($self.val()) * parseInt($("#qtr1-revenue-month-" + idNum).val());
    alert(idNum + ": " + product);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="qtr1-revenue-month-1" id="qtr1-revenue-month-1" class="qtr-revenue editable" value="1000" />
<input type="text" name="qtr1-revenue-month-2" id="qtr1-revenue-month-2" class="qtr-revenue editable" value="2000" />
<input type="text" name="qtr1-revenue-month-3" id="qtr1-revenue-month-3" class="qtr-revenue editable" value="3000" />

<input type="text" name="qtr1-margin-month-1" id="qtr1-margin-month-1" class="qtr editable margin" value="10" />
<input type="text" name="qtr1-margin-month-2" id="qtr1-margin-month-2" class="qtr editable margin" value="45" />
<input type="text" name="qtr1-margin-month-3" id="qtr1-margin-month-3" class="qtr editable margin" value="75" />
```

You can see here that this `change` callback will work for many of the Text Fields. It will find the relative field based on the ID, so for example, `qtr1-margin-month-1` will look for `qtr1-revenue-month-1`.

You can use `blur` event if you want, yet `change` might be better. It really depends on what you're doing.